# ERROR: Parsing Cookie Using Json.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies, json.net

I am getting error while parsing cookie created using jquery in asp.net.It throws error at line 3:
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0.

```
HttpCookie MyCookie = Request.Cookies["cart"];
Response.Write(MyCookie.Value.ToString());            
var myobjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CookieCart>(MyCookie.Value.ToString());
```

Sample Cookie Value:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "thumbnail": "/cocosamples/images/cocopeat/branded/430041-0014_1_t.jpg",
    "title": "cocopeat",
    "url": "product.html",
    "price": "$ 250.00",
    "qty": 3
  }
]
```

CookieCart Class

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
public string Price { get; set; }
public int Qty { get; set; }
```

MyCookie Value:

> %5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22thumbnail%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A52781%2FASVOnline%2Ftheme%2Fimages%2Fwomen%2Fskirt%2F430041-0014_1_t.jpg%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Inceptos%20orci%20hac%20libero%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22product.html%22%2C%22price%22%3A%22%24%20250.00%22%2C%22qty%22%3A10%7D%5D

Cookie cart

Comment: how is your class `CookieCart` looks like?

Comment: when i try to read the same cookie value using JavaScriptSerializer i got error Invalid JSON primitive: .

Comment: you need `Server.UrlDecode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cookie value is encoded. Use [`Server.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also your JSON is returning multiple `CookieCart` items since it is an array having `[]`. You need to de-serialize your object to either `List<CookieCart>` or `CookieCart[]` like:

```
var myobjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CookieCart>>
                             (Server.UrlDecode(MyCookie.Value.ToString()));
```

and then to get a single object:

```
CookieCart singleItem = myobjects.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Now i am getting the following error... Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'CookieCart' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'CookieCart' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @padmaCybonyx, Fixed that in my answer. You are basically getting a collection of `CookieCart`. Check the updated code.

Comment: good catch...u saved me a day... had been trying from afternoon using various methods.